# Can the Prestidigitation cantrip flavor magical food?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, food-and-drink

The [*prestidigitation*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation) cantrip's description lists the following effect as one option:

> You chill, warm, or **flavor** up to 1 cubic foot of nonliving material for 1 hour.

The [*create food and water*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-food-and-water) spell's description say:

> The food is **bland** but nourishing, ...

My DM has established that [*goodberry*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry) also follows the same pattern with *create food and water*, they are bland. Then it occurred to us that we can use *prestidigitation* to flavor the food (and berry) created so that we can basically write off the need for rations when dungeon-delving.

**Can *prestidigitation* flavor magical food?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

The food made by create food and water isn't magical. It was made with magic, but the duration of the spell is instantaneous so it can't be dispelled or negated with an antimagic field. It's just ordinary, bland but nutritious food once it has been made.

Goodberries on the other hand are magical, however prestidigitation states that it works on nonliving material. It doesn't say anything about nonmagical. As such it will work fine.

I don't see why you are worried about the flavor though. The food and water created by the create food and water spell is bland, but nutritious. Each casting can keep at least 30 people fed and watered per day. Unless you DM is introducing some kind of house rules that will be enough to keep the party going. I've only ever had one DM take note of rations anyway.

Comment: we agree to not use goodberry and create food and water during exploration - roleplaywise - because we lived through them for a month and we had enough. After we get back to civilization, we bring supplies because we don't want to eat goodberry/create food and water, ever, again, unless in emergency.

Comment: @Vylix Unless you're bringing fresh food with which to cook the bland food from Create Food and Water is going to taste better than rations. Rations are things that won't go bad easily like Hardtack and salted/cured meats. Neither of those are super appetizing